# Script to check if a website is opened on our system

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, psutil

Is it possible to have a python script to first check if chromium is opened on our system (raspberry pi), if opened then the script needs to check if a particular website; for example, https://stackoverflow.com, is opened or not in chrome. It is to be done on Linux OS.
Am new to this.

Thanks for the help

```py
import psutil

def if_process_is_running_by_exename(exename='chrome.exe'):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        if proc.info['name'] == exename:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we need much more details including your code that you tried so far

Comment: @Prophet as of now I have tried with psutil which checks if browser is opened or not but am not able to check if a particular website is opened on that browser
```
import psutil

def if_process_is_running_by_exename(exename='chrome.exe'):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
        # This will check if there exists any process running with executable name
        if proc.info['name'] == exename:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Please add this and any other relevant details inside your question.

Comment: @Prophet  Have added please check it out

Comment: You should now that executable files on linux don't use the`.exe` extension. Furthermore there isn't chrome for the raspberry pi as far as I now, it's called "chromium" and its like chrome's open source brother.

Comment: @-d-k-bo ...ok but how to know if a particular website is opened or not?